# Unique attribute in has_many association with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, simple-form, nested-forms, has-many

I have the following problem I don't know how to solve:
ModelA has_many ModelB

ModelB has an bool attribute "default". ModelA must have only one ModelB entry with true "default" attribute. Now, if a new ModelB with "default" set to true is added to ModelA that already contains a ModelB with "default" set to true, the old ModelB will be set to false and the newly added stays true.

I'm using simple_form and cocoon gem to manipulate the data in the views. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a `before_save` callback to the ModelB, where you update all ModelBs from ModalA